# How to restart devstack after rebooting Ubuntu system?

Tags: openstack, devstack

7.25 2017
I've installed the newest devstack on Ubuntu17.04. The version of Openstack is Ocata. After rebooting the Ubuntu, I find it unable to start the OpenStack service.

After searching lots of pages, most of them are outdated. In my devstack direcionary, no rejoin-stack.sh, no screen-stackrc.

So, how can I restart the devstack without ./unstack.sh and then ./stack?

[No restart-script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox84z.png)

Answer (score 1):

Devstack previously had a `./rejoin-stack.sh` that allows to resume the state of your devstack.

However, this patch removes that script.

https://review.openstack.org/#/c/291453/

Based on the description on that patch, the best way is to `./unstack.sh` and `./clean.sh`, then `./stack.sh` again.